# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't kill the process that suddenly uses all the RAM, which causes the system to crash?

Tags: 20.04, ram, crash, optimization

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, now if i am not mistaking, Ubuntu has a built in feature that kills a process if it suddenly uses all the RAM to stop system crash, i have seen it happen ( for example it kills any python scripts that suddenly uses all the system memory or something, and says killed in the terminal)

The problem is many times this mechanism doesn't work, and it causes my system to crash (its a python script that uses all the memory), I am doing machine learning stuff and i cannot predict how much some of my scripts might use, and i was expecting Ubuntu to just basically kill an app when it suddenly uses all the system memory, but it doesn't work, and my system crashes (everything hangs, no mouse movement or anything, but using REISUB i can reboot the system)

sometimes its not even sudden surge in RAM usage, the script just keeps allocating more RAM and RAM and when it reaches the limit my system basically freezes and Ubuntu doesn't stop it!! i thought there was a defensive mechanism for this situation?

so my question is :

How can i tell Ubuntu to kill any app that suddenly uses all the free RAM available? basically what is the best solution for me to stop the crashes other that changing my scripts?

edit : is there anyway to tell the OS to kill the python process in out of memory situations, no matter the process id? meaning kill any process with the name of python when its out of memory.

edit2 :

output of free -h :

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       4.1Gi       218Mi       469Mi        11Gi        10Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       946Mi       1.1Gi
```

edit3:

out put of sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/choom.1.html ?

Comment: @Rinzwind is there anyway i can use this or some other command to tell the OS to kill the python process in out of memory situations, no matter the process id? because i can't know the PID of it in advance, i just want the system to kill any python process when its out of memory, any way to do that?

Comment: Do you have swap? Edit your question and show me `free -h`.

Comment: @heynnema yes i do, i edited the question.

Comment: I'll put together an answer for you...

Comment: Show me `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: @heynnema its vm.swappiness = 60

Comment: Thanks. We MAY change that later. Let me know if the increased /swapfile helps.

Comment: Is there a way to modify your python script to monitor/use less memory?

Comment: @heynnema unfortunately no

Comment: Have you had a chance to try your script with the increased /swapfile?

Comment: @heynnema no but i will try it out in 15 minutes

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Can you run your script now?

Comment: @heynnema yes thank you, it basically gives me enough time to kill it manually, but ubuntu still doesn't kill by itself most of the times (but sometimes does)

Comment: Temporarily try `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80`. If that improves things further, I'll show you how to make it permanent across reboots.

Comment: @heynnema well it has not happened again so far

Comment: Is that with vm.swappiness set to 80?

Comment: @heynnema even before that, it stopped after the swap size change. one question tho, what does this swappiness=80 command do, putting it in a simple way?

Comment: Oh, it wasn't clear from your prior comment that the problem was completely solved, hence my comment about trying a different vm.swappiness value. vm.swappiness sets the ratio of RAM vs SWAP. Values near 10 favor RAM, and values near 90 favor SWAP, and by my suggesting =80, it would have forced the system to use SWAP more, and in your case, leave more RAM for your script/app. However, if it's all running fine now, we'll leave it at 60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's increase your /swapfile from 2G to 4G (maybe more later, if your python script requires it)...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the swap file and delete it

```
sudo swapoff /swapfile
sudo rm  /swapfile
```

Create a new swap file of the desired size.

```
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
```

In this command, adjust 4G to the size you want.